# Css hover+click/touch weird behavior on touch devices

Tags: html, css, touch

I know the title is too general. I couldn't find a specific title.

Here is the sample https://jsfiddle.net/Exlord/1soagsL5/

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item with submenu &gt;
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li id='clickable'>item1</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var el = document.getElementById('clickable');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}, false);
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

li {
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

@media all and (min-width: 481px) {
  ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Try it, it's a very simple menu, hover the middle item *item with submenu*, a simple submenu will be shown with simple CSS `:hover`.

Click on the last item, it has a click event, it will fire correctly.

Now open this in Chrome's mobile device mod with touch simulation.

Click/touch the *item with submenu*, the submenu will open inside the parent element. This is the expected behavior.

Now click/touch the last element. The click event will not fire.

How can I fix this with CSS only `hover`?

UPDATE : As far as I can tell the problem is that on first touch the last hovered element (`li` with submenu) gets unhovered and the submenu `ul` gets hidden and the parent `ul`'s height shrinks and the `li` element that was under the touched point moves up, so its not under the touched point anymore and it does not get clicked/touched !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you figured out the cause on your own. The click target does seem to move away before event reaches the element.

The easiest solution I see is to use some supplementary Javascript to open and close the submenu on clicks. You use Javascript for the `#clickable` event anyway so a little more won't be detrimental, just as long as you keep the `:hover` for cases where Javascript is fails to load.

---

**Original Answer**

> Touch devices do not have a hover state, due to the hardware
>   interface. Browser makers chose a compromise to allow for sites which
>   rely on it. Whenever a hover event/style is defined for an element the
>   first tap will trigger that effect instead of the click. A second tap
>   should, at least in most cases, trigger the original click event.
>
> For your particular case you don't have a `ul` within the
>   `li#clickable`, but the `:hover` is still detected and the browser
>   behaves as it was designed. Excluding your `#clickable` from the hover
>   event will theoretically fix it (I am not able to test it myself at
>   this time).
>
> ```
> li:not(#clickable):hover > ul {
>   display: block;
> }
> ```

Comment: nope, that did not work. the problem i think is that on first touch the last hovered element gets unhovered, the submenu `ul` gets hidden and the `li` element that was under the touched point moves up, so its not under the touched point anymore and its does not get clicked/touched !!!!

Comment: Just to clarify, since I didn't say so in the answer, the intent was to replace your `li:hover > ul` declaration with my code snippet. Leaving both would make nothing change.

Comment: the menu it self actually is being generated by js and its not a static html. I was hoping to handle the show/hide with css only, But for now I ended up adding a js solution for small screens only.